# Adding names to an IP address without failing the batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ping

I want to use a batch file to ping a set of servers. The batch file works and reports ok or failed. All I want is to have it display a name of the server in the check.

This is what I use in the batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\List of IPs.txt) do ping -n 1 %%a >nul && (echo %%a ok) || (echo %%a failed to respond) 
pause
```

In the text file it points to is just a list of IPs, how do I make it so I can see a name next to the IP?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens if you remove `>nul`? and what happens when you use the `/a` option with your `ping` command? Do you see the resolved host name then? Also what happens when you use the `for` command's `usebackq` option and doublequote your text file name?

Comment: Where do you want the name to come from?

Comment: If the device is registered properly with a name server.  The OP said "servers" but there's no reason this couldn't be used for printers or other network devices that do not register with a name server.

Comment: @avery_larry OP specifically says __"In the text file it points to is just a list of IPs"__

Comment: And it specifically says **"how do I make it so I can see a name next to the IP?"**  Which I do not presume to preclude the possibility of modifying the text file.

Comment: Hence the comment by @Compo referring to resolving the name to DNS using the -a option. It is 100% clear that it is what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

just insert another `for /f` loop to get the name:

```
@echo off
SetLocal 
for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("List of IPs.txt") do (
  for /f %%b in ('"ping -n 1 %%a >nul && (echo ok) || (echo failed to respond) "') do (
    for /f "tokens=1*" %%m in ('nslookup %%a  ^|findstr /b "Name:"') do (
     echo %%a   %%n %%b
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score -2):

One option is to format your file to have the IP and the name you are interested in.

```
192.168.1.200 server1
192.168.1.201 server2
192.168.1.202 printer1
192.168.1.203 that one stupid printer in the back
```

Then you can read both from the file.
One thing I'll note -- your method of checking pings is not consistent.  You can get an errorlevel 0 even if the ping actually fails (from a valid response of "unreachable").  Instead (in English) a successful ping always includes "ttl=".  Thus you would do this:

**untested**

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims= " %%a in ("C:\List of IPs.txt") do ping -n 1 %%a ^|find /i "ttl=" >nul && (echo %%b at %%a is ok) || (echo %%b at %%a failed to respond)
pause
```

nslookup and/or ping -a can be leveraged if you have dns working with everything you're trying to access.

Based on comment, I've added the following solution that works on my English Windows 10 computer with the text file above:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims= " %%a in ("C:\temp\List of IPs.txt") do ping -n 1 -w 1500 %%a |find /i "ttl=" >nul &&echo %%b at %%a is ok||echo %%b at %%a failed to respond
pause
```

Note there is a space between the equal sign and the double quote at `delims= "`

Output:

```
server1 at 192.168.1.200 is ok
server2 at 192.168.1.201 is ok
printer1 at 192.168.1.202 is ok
that one stupid printer in the back at 192.168.1.203 failed to respond
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Good Day

Every time I add a name to the IP's the ping test fails. I cannot figure out the correct format to simply have a name next to the ping test.

Comment: Post more information.  Are you modifying the list of ips.txt file?  Did you modify the `for` statement?

Comment: I tried modifying the list sorry. I have not tried modifying the for statement.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and put a sample of the new text file and the current relevant batch file lines?  Can you also show us the output?